# Perl multiline search replace

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find and corresponding block and uncomment the second line in text file using perl one-liner. Im fairly new to using complex regex, so your help is very much appreciated! Also is there a way to debug one-liners?

Here is what I have so far, which does not work even though I tested it using a interactive regex tester:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/#[\s]*label2[\n]#(.*)/${1}/gi;' file.txt
```

The text file looks like the following

```
#   label1
#variable=foobar1

#   label2
#variable=foobar2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(#\s*label2\s*\n)#/$1/s' infile
```

The `-0777` slurps the whole file, parens do grouping over the key line to use it again in the replacement part, and remove what it's outside of it, the `#` character. It yields:

```
#   label1
#variable=foobar1

#   label2
variable=foobar2
```

About the debugging, I think it works the same that from a script, use `-d` switch to activate it. Simply put each instruction in a different line to visualize it fine.

Comment: The `/s` modifier changes how `.` behaves, but there's no `.` in your regex.

Comment: BTW, where I get some documentation/information on that -0777 flag?

Comment: @user1940015 Run [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) (I've linked to the online version in case you don't have `perldoc` on your machine).

Answer (score -2):

One awk solution if you are not limited to perl:

```
awk 'f{f=sub(/^#/,"")};/label2/{f=1}1' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am limited to using perl for my case